# MS Visual Studio not working properly after starting the application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

MS Visual Studio not working properly after starting the application.
Iam using VS 2019, it stops working on very often.
Issue is like after starting the app, no buttons are working on UI.
It was working fine 2 days ago. But with same code base, no buttons are working on UI.
Same branch code is functioning properly on my colleague's systems who is using VS 2017.
Wonder if someone can throw some light on this issue.

Thanks,
Kalyani.

Comment: Is it the VisualStudio UI which is corrupted or your App's UI? Do you start your App with or without debugging (F5 or Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Its my App's UI, tried both F5 and Ctrl+F5, same behavior upon app start.

Comment: So why do you then write that Visual Studion is not working? Please provide more details what "not working" in fact means. Are they not visible? Or disabled? Or do not call your event handler? Or is there a problem within the event handler? Also, please specify the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Comment: @KlausGütter The same code base working fine for my colleague, on my system after starting the app with/without debugging, buttons are not responding, its not calling the event handler, but they are visible also not disabled. using ASP.NET as UI framework. Thanks.

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] your question to add this information to the question itself. If it is ASP.NET, also the used Browser is of interest. And please include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You said that it is working in your colleague computer So the code is correct.

Once again check your code is same.

If it is same then the problem is with Visual Studio.
The Solution is:

- Go to Visual Studio Installer.
- and Repair the VS.
- Make sure you have backup of projects stored in `%USER PROFILE%\source\repos\.`
  because this default vs projects location.